# Change css based on the page url

Tags: 7, theming

I am using drupal 7. I wanted to change the colors of the block and everything for certain pages. The ThemeKey module works fine but i have to do all the block configurations again in this. This is tedious. Since i want to change only the css any other module will solve ma problem?

Comment: You are completely right about ThemeKey. While it does serve a specific purpose, it's usually best to keep everything in a single theme, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `body` element will have a boatload of classes on it.  This does vary by theme, but typically there will be a class like

```
body.page-the-url-for-this-page
```

that you can use in your CSS.

Do a view source on various pages and take a look.  Or, use the Inspect Element feature of Firefox's Firebug or Google Chrome, or the Firefox Web Developer extension.

If the class isn't there, you can do something like

```
function thetheme_preprocess_html (&$variables)
{
  $variables['classes_array'][] = "page-" . str_replace("/", "-", request_uri());
}
```

You may also want to investigate the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module, which can aid in section-specific features for a site.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good approach, and very succinct. I think the following code works better, since 'replace' throws an error:

```
function thetheme_preprocess_html (&$variables)
{
  $variables['classes_array'][] = "page-" . str_replace("/", "-", request_uri());
}
```